# Apache mod_php_memory_usage prints "%zu" instead of useful data

Tags: php, apache2

Using the below `LogFormat`:

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b php(%{mod_php_memory_usage}n)" vhost_combined_memory
```

Apache does not seem to output the memory used by PHP for each request:

```
IP - - [04/Feb/2014:23:22:49 +1300] "GET /icinga-web/modules/cronks/statusOverall/json?_dc=1391509810557 HTTP/1.1" 200 554 php(%zu)
IP - - [04/Feb/2014:23:22:50 +1300] "GET /icinga-web/modules/cronks/monitorPerformance/json?_dc=1391509810614 HTTP/1.1" 200 378 php(%zu)
IP - - [04/Feb/2014:23:23:49 +1300] "GET /icinga-web/modules/appkit/servertime HTTP/1.1" 200 33 php(%zu)
```

Instead of a number, `%zu` appears.

Is there a change I can make on the server to cause this datum to properly appear in my logs?

Comment: Looking at apr_vformatter() in apr_snprintf.c, %z is not a supported format.

Answer (score 0):

Running into this problem myself.  The problem doesn't lie in php or even Apache httpd.  It's the APR.  They implemented their own printf expansion instead of using stdio.

So you can see around line 850...  https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/apr/apr/trunk/strings/apr_snprintf.c?view=markup

...the supported characters that they'll expand does not include the 'z' character.

So I don't believe there's fix without modifying source code.  Switching the %zu to %lu in the php source will probably do the trick.